# How to disable mouse wheel scrolling while the cursor is on the scrollbar of the datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a need to disable the use of the mouse wheel (customer specification) in data grid views currently I have tried in the derived datagridview class

```
VerticleScrollBar.MouseWheel += WheelHandled;
MouseWheel += WheelHandled;

private void WheelHandled(object sender, MouseeventArgs e){
    HandledMouseEventArgs mouseWheelEvent = e as HandledMouseEventArgs;
    if(mouseWheelEvent != null){
        mouseWheelEvent.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This has prevented wheel scrolling when inside the cells, but if the cursor is over the scrollbar the mouse wheel still works and I don't know why. I would prefer to avoid using wnd_proc if possible

Answer (score 0):

It'll be too late without trapping the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages of the protected [`VScrollBar`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,5222). In your implementation, you can subscribe to the `VScrollBar.MouseWheel` event like so:

```cs
// The first control in the collection is HScrollBar.
// The second is VScrollBar.
var vs = dataGridView1.Controls[1] as VScrollBar;

vs.MouseWheel += (s, e) =>
{
    // ...
};
```

Or in your derived class:

```cs
public class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    public DataGridViewEx()
    {
        var vs = Controls[1] as VScrollBar;

        vs.MouseWheel += (s, e) =>
        {
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```

However, handling the event to set `(e as HandledMouseEventArgs).Handled = true;` has no effect. Again, it's too late to do so. You need to take an action at the right time. For that, you have to create a custom `DataGridView` and subclass the scrollbar's native window to prevent processing the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages.

```cs
public class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    public DataGridViewEx()
    {
        new ScrollBarNativeWin(VerticalScrollBar);
        // If you need too
        // new ScrollBarNativeWin(HorizontalScrollBar);
    }

    private class ScrollBarNativeWin : NativeWindow
    {
        const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;

        public ScrollBarNativeWin(ScrollBar scrollBar)
        {
            scrollBar.HandleCreated += (s, e) => AssignHandle(scrollBar.Handle);
            scrollBar.HandleDestroyed += (s, e) => ReleaseHandle();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {                
            if (m.Msg != WM_MOUSEWHEEL) base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```