# Janus MultiColumnCombo how to stop mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: vb.net

I want to disable mouse wheel scrolling when a mouse cursor hovers over the MultiColumnCombo. I've tried windows combobox techiques to cancel the event but have had no success. The has an event exposed but I tried to add a handler but it does not get raise. The MultiColumnCombo has an internal textbox and dropdownlist. I've tried to addhandlers to the wheelmouse events for both of these sub controls. I was able to log the wheelmouse moves to the console but e.cancel did not stop the wheelmouse movement. My hunch is the event handler needs to override the base textbox event. I think mine is just shadowing it. Any question is how can I override an event that is in a compiled control?

Public Class MyMultiColumnCombo
Inherits Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.MultiColumnCombo

```
'Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseWheel(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
'    MsgBox("test")
'    Dim mwe As HandledMouseEventArgs = DirectCast(e, HandledMouseEventArgs)
'    mwe.Handled = True
'End Sub

Public Sub New()

    Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
    Me.TextBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan
    Me.DropDownList.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red


    AddHandler Me.DropDownList.MouseWheel, AddressOf Me.DropDownList_MouseWheel

    AddHandler Me.TextBox.MouseWheel, AddressOf Me.TextBox_MouseWheel

    'AddHandler Me.MouseWheel, AddressOf Me.Me_MouseWheel


End Sub

Private DropDownList_MouseWheel_Counter As Long
Private TextBox_MouseWheel_Counter As Long

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseWheel(e As MouseEventArgs)

    Dim mwe As HandledMouseEventArgs = DirectCast(e, HandledMouseEventArgs)
    mwe.Handled = True

    Debug.WriteLine("OnMouseWheel ")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDown(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("OnDropDown")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnTextBoxTextChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("OnTextBoxTextChanged")
End Sub

Private Sub DropDownList_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As HandledMouseEventArgs)
    DropDownList_MouseWheel_Counter += 1
    Debug.WriteLine("DropDownList_MouseWheel " & DropDownList_MouseWheel_Counter)

    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Protected Sub TextBox_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As HandledMouseEventArgs)
    TextBox_MouseWheel_Counter += 1
    Debug.WriteLine("TextBox_MouseWheel " & TextBox_MouseWheel_Counter)



    e.Handled = True

    Debug.WriteLine("Me.VerticalScroll.Value: " & Me.VerticalScroll.Value)


    Dim v As Integer = Me.VerticalScroll.Value
    v += e.Delta \ 10
    v = Math.Max(v, 0)
    Me.VerticalScroll.Value = v


    'Dim mwe As HandledMouseEventArgs = DirectCast(e, HandledMouseEventArgs)
    'mwe.Handled = True

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Same problem & suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818410/14171304). Just subclass the control(s) you want to disable the mouse wheel scrolling.